# Problem changing tooltip css in Joomla 3

Tags: css, joomla-3.9

I'm trying to change the css properties of the tooltip css in Joomla 3.9.
That is, when you hover over a text-label and a description appears right to it. I can't find the corresponding css class, not even with "force state: hover" in the browsers inspector tools. Does anyone know how to do it?

Edit: Please see this image.

[image: The mouse hovers over label "Name *" and tooltip appears on the right]

The mouse hovers over label "Name *" and Tooltip appears on the right. I want to give a background-color to the tooltip.

Comment: I edited my initial question.

Comment: Where are you that you don't have the classic tooltip graphic? https://imgur.com/a/xDptjFs Can you show us how to recreate your issue?  Also, please take the [tour].

Comment: I took the tour. My template comes from a template generator. It was like this when I installed it. I would like to know what class the tooltip uses so that I can rewrite that class but 1) the tooltip class isn't shown in my inspector because it's a :hover pseudo-class. 2) forcing :hover state "on" in the inspector doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was: The Tooltip didn't have the styling I wanted.
The quest was: To know the tooltip css class to be able to alter it.
The solution: I googled the internet for the tooltip css class (the jquery suggestion didn't work for me) and altered the `.popover` class (tooltip) so that it looks the way I wanted.

**CSS added:** to templates/$template_name$/style.css

```
.popover {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #A10C27;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

**Resulting Image on the Website:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The base HTML generated by Bootstrap tooltips looks like this:

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Once triggered, outer `div` also receives position classes (`top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right`) as well as `fade` and `in`:

```
<div class="tooltip fade top in">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner">Tooltip Text</div>
</div>
```

> I can't find the corresponding css class, not even with "force state:
>   hover" in the browsers inspector tools.

Changing state in inspector does not trigger JavaScript. Instead, you can enter this into console to show the tooltip:

```
jQuery('#example').tooltip('show');
```

Where `#example` is the selector of the element containing the tooltip. When you run this code, the tooltip will be generated and its markup will appear in inspector.

Comment: The ID and the Class
jQuery('#jform_title-lbl').tooltip('show');
and
jQuery('.hasPopover.required').tooltip('show');
don't get what I want.
The Popover doesn't show up.